# $ \sum_{p } \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log p}{p^k}$ is Convergent

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

How can I show the sum $ \sum_{p } \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log p}{p^k}$ where $p$ varies over all the primes, is Convergent?

I tried comparing with the convergent series $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p^2}$, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can explicitly evaluate the inner sum. It becomes pretty clear how to proceed then.

Comment: I am getting the series $\sum_{p} \frac{\log p}{p(p-1)}$

Comment: Correct. Is it obvious that this converges, or do you need an intermediate step?

Comment: No..it is not obvious still..I know $\frac{\log p}{p(p-1)} < \frac{1}{ p^{3/2}}$ Can we show $ \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}$ converges?

Comment: O.it is the obvious..since it is bounded by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n^{3/2}}$.